# Is there a way to do a "bulk rename" of specific fields in classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

We have hundreds of java classes that use `private static final OurTracer tracer`, and hundreds more that go `private static final OurTracer TRACER`. Now we want to unify that.

I know I can use "Structural search" to find all the corresponding classes with a `tracer` field, and then manually do a refactor to `TRACER`. But as said, this is about hundreds of files.

I tried the approach outlined in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#structural_replace), but the problem: that only replaces the name in the field declaration. It doesn't do a real, class wide refactoring.

Thus: is there a way in IntelliJ to do "bulk refactor" a specific field (without manual actions for each file)?

Comment: I believe this can be done in a few steps: 1. replace the field declaration with itself + the new field 2. now you can replace the usages of the fields with the new field 3. remove the old field declarations.

Comment: You mean like: 1. duplicate the field ... 2. string replace `tracer.` to `TRACER.` 3. drop the first original field? Sounds like a strategy. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, step 2 could be done with "replace structurally" too, I think. (I don't actually know how to use replace structurally, so this is just an idea)

Comment: Duplicating works ... but I have to figure if there is a way to keep the indenting the same. That might be tricky.

Comment: There is a checkbox in the replace structurally dialog box that says "reformat". Does that not work?

Comment: Is your `TRACER` a constant? As in, an object that functions like a constant immutable value? If not, by code conventions it shouldn't be in capitals. "Tracer" sounds like this is some singleton related to a tracing framework - that wouldn't be a constant so it should be in lower case.

Comment: It is not a singelton, the full decl goes like `private static final OurTracer TRACER = new OurTracer(some params)` ... and yes, it is like an immutable object. Thats way we decided to go ALL UPPER.

Comment: Please file a new feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thank you